# Simulation of the Wiener process

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

While simulating the standart Wiener process one should use the expression 
$$W(t+\Delta t)-W(t)=\sqrt{\Delta t}\, \xi_t, $$
where $\xi_t \sim N(0,1)$. Explain me, please, how has the multiplier $\sqrt{\Delta t}$ come up?

Comment: See it as a diffusion term. An image : If I place a drop of colored liquid in the water, the rate of increase of the radius of the diluted color circle is proportional not to time but to the square root of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that $W(t + \Delta t) - W(t) \sim N(0, \Delta t)$. If $\xi_t \sim N(0,1)$ then $\sqrt{\Delta t} \, \xi_t \sim N(0,\Delta t)$